# Youtube Video not working within fancybox on ipad when using jquery.fancybox-media.js

Tags: jquery, ipad, youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to use youtube video within a fancybox with responsive features such that it can adjust its dimensions according to the device for that i had used jquery.fancybox-media.js and it works well on desktop but video doesn't play on iPad .

Visit http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ then clicking on Youtube(iframe) it only plays on desktop but not on iPad.

It uses jquery.fancybox-media.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since fancybox version 2.1.0 there is an `iframe` API option that allows you to preload the contents of an iframe; the default value is `true`.

Unfortunately, since jQuery v1.9+ I have seen that this option somehow creates issues while trying to display `iframe` content, specifically with streamed media or PDF documents.

As a workaround, I have been disabling the `iframe` preload and that has fixed many of the issues reported.

Fancybox uses `iframe` type for youtube videos, but their homepage still uses the default value (`true`), however in your own web pages, you should disable this option and your youtube videos will work in iPhone/iPad with no issue :

This *hrml* for instance

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3l8MwU0IjMI?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1">show youtube in fancybox</a>
```

... with this script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    width: 620, // or whatever
    height: 420,
    type: "iframe",
    iframe : {
      preload: false
    }
  });
}); // ready
```

... should work just fine.

**NOTE** that the `autoplay=1` parameter doesn't work in mobile devices, so you still need to `click` on the video to start (which make sense to me since you may not want to waste your data plan unintentionally)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rVLaC/show/)** in iPad ;)

**EDIT** : if you don't want to have a fixed `iframe` size (responsiveness), then just get rid of the size options like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    iframe : {
      preload: false
    }
  });
}); // ready
```

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rVLaC/1/show/)** in iPad