# Fancybox - Embedded YouTube (using YouTube API) doesn't load on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, fancybox

I am using Fancybox to display videos that are uploaded to YouTube. I want to carry out actions when the video has ended (in this case, moving from the video to the next element in the group - an image), so I am also using the YouTube API.

The page works perfectly fine on desktop browsers (and I think Android but I haven't tested that extensively yet), but on my iPhone it fails to load the video. The overlay is coming up, but it appears to try to autoplay the video and then becomes black.

I am currently using jQuery 1.8.3 (I tried it with 1.10 but it didn't work, so I gave downgrading a shot) and Fancybox 2.1.5.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="content" id="main">
    <div id="logo">
        <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" id="logo-link" data-fancybox-group="group01"href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bc0qNwaSxlM"></a>
        <a class="fancybox" id="v-link" data-fancybox-group="group01" data-fancybox-type="image" href="img/superhard_v.png" title="<a href='#' id='return-link'>or return to ihardyou</a>"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
    // Initialise the fancyBox after the DOM is loaded
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox")
            .attr('rel', 'gallery')
            .fancybox({
                helpers: {
                    media: {},
                    overlay : {
                        css : {
                            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                youtube : {
                    vq: 'hd1080'
                },
                padding: 0,
                margin: 30,
                autoSize: false,
                arrows: false,
                'closeBtn' : false,
                beforeShow  : function() {
                    // Find the iframe ID
                    var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');

                    // Create video player object and add event listeners
                    var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });

                    if (this.index === 1) {
                        $('.fancybox-outer').css("padding-bottom","100px");
                    }  
                },
                afterShow: function() {
                    if (this.index === 1) {
                        $("img.fancybox-image").click(function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            newLocation = "vanity/";
                            $('body').fadeOut(1000, newPage);
                        });

                        $('#return-link').click(function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $.fancybox.close();
                        });  
                    }               
                },
                tpl: {
                    wrap : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin" style="background-color:transparent;"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>'
                },
                iframe: {
                    preload: false
                }
            });

    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// Fires when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    // Go to the image after the current one is finished playing
    if (event.data === 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){$.fancybox.next()},1250);
    }
}
```

I put in `autoSize` and `preload: false` for `iframe` because of solutions I came across from other peoples questions, but they did not work. I was particularly hopeful the latter would work because of [this question and the example JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587772/youtube-video-not-working-within-fancybox-on-ipad-when-using-jquery-fancybox-med/16595607#16595607), but it didn't work, which led me to believe that maybe it's an issue with the API? I also looked at the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz/) on the Fancybox homepage which uses the API, and it also did not work on my iPhone, further confirming my suspicion.

If anyone has a workaround or any idea of how to fix this, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Why not re-check the various examples used in the fancybox website:

**You can try this:**
**Html**

```
<li>
        <a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">Youtube (iframe)</a>
    </li>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Our check their official fiddle for youtube iframe: [This is their fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz/)

Html:

```
<!-- This loads the YouTube IFrame Player API code -->
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque">Video #1</a>

<br />

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cYplvwBvGA4?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque">Video #2</a>
```

You can check out the remainin'

Comment: It might be wise to check out the official youtube iframe fiddle yourself on an iPad or and iPhone so you can see that it doesn't work.