# fancyBox - YouTube Video Won't Display

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, lightbox

Here is my HTML:

```
<a class="various fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzBk4-awY40"><div id="video_nav"><h3 class="nav_text">Video</h3></div></a>
```

And jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
});
```

I modified my code from a demo using the most recent version of fancyBox, and a video will not display unless I use the video used in the demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this URL format

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzBk4-awY40
```

...won't work with `iframe` mode (you are setting `fancybox.iframe` class in your link).

You may rather use youtube's `embedded` format, which works on devices that don't support *flash*

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/PzBk4-awY40
```

Additionally, you can add the `?autoplay=1` trailing parameter if you want your videos to start right after fancybox is opened

**<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1v1we4v8/)</kbd>**

**NOTES**:

- If you really want to stick to the `/watch?v=` URL format (the links are set by the user or dynamically) then remove the class `fancybox.iframe` from your link and use the fancybox *media helper* instead. Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples ==> extended functionality for more.
- to avoid a known iframe issue (mostly with IE) I would advise you to set iframe preload to `false`, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595607/1055987 for more